# Some pages ask for authentication although user is already authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

In an MVC 4 project, i've used ASP web form authentication and is implemented in a base controller.
There are no specific roles created. Just simple combination of user name , password and authentication cookies.
It works all fine in development phase.
But after hosting at client, i found out that at specific area called Report, it asks for another authentication using browsers input form and is not authenticated even by original user name and password.
But hosting at my own development pc no such authentication is required.
What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 'Report' folder permissions on disk? Looks like the browser is asking you for windows authentication.